# Declaring a variable outside a function in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter. I'm trying to output a view again after clicking a submit but the view has a variable from the controller, but when I tried it, it doesn't work.

```
<?php
    class Site extends CI_Controller{

        public $data1['value'] = "What to insert";

        public function index(){
            $this->load->view('home',$this->data1);
        }

    public function get_product(){
            $data = array(
                'product_name' => $this->input->post('prod_name')
            );
            $this->site_model->insert_product($data);
            $this->load->view('home',$this->data1);
        }

    }
?>
```

Here's my view:

```
<div id="container">
<h1><?php echo $data1;?></h1>

    <?php echo form_open('site/get_product'); ?>

    <p>
        <label for="product">Product Name </label>
        <input type="text" id="product" name="prod_name" />
    </p>    

    <input type="submit" name="submit_but" value="submit">

<?php echo form_close(); ?>

</div>
```

In `get_product` I need to call again the view but I know it'll be such a hassle if I'm going to declare it again inside the function.

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\code_igniter\application\controllers\site.php on line 9
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean exactly?

Comment: im having an error.. sorry forgot to include.. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\code_igniter\application\controllers\site.php on line 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

__construct function is calling every time you run the script so you can add your constant values in this function for view or other usage.

```
<?php
class Site extends CI_Controller{
    public $data1 = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->data1['value'] = "bla bla";
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('home',$this->data1);
    }

    public function get_product(){
        $data = array(
        'product_name' => $this->input->post('prod_name')
        );
        $this->site_model->insert_product($data);
        $this->load->view('home',$this->data1);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The description of the actual problem or error is vague at best, but I'll guess that this is the problem:

```
public $data1['value'] = "What to insert";
```

That's not a valid declaration of a property. If you want to declare the property "`$data1`" as being an array, then you have to do so:

```
public $data1 = array('value' => "What to insert");
```