# How to declare global variable session data

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, global

This is my controller. I need to use the three lines above as global variables. So that all functions can use it. How will I do this ?

```
class Some_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    $this->load->library('session'); //Must be global                     
    $this->session->set_userdata('email', 'email@hp.com'); //Must be global
    $data['current_user']=$this->session->userdata('email'); //Must be global


   public function index(){

    $data['people'] = $this->some_model->getPeople();
    $data['mapList'] = $this->some_model->getMapped();
    $data['appServList'] = $this->some_model->getApp_serv();


    $this->load->view('templates/header.php',$data);
    $this->load->view('some_page/index.php',$data);
    /*Serves as the homepage. Shows the list for services, mapped services to an application and the list for application,
    from here you can easily add edit and hide items*/

}
```

Comment: Once you set a session.You can call it from anywhere.no need to set it globally...!

Answer (score 1):

For session to start automatically you can set `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');` in autoload.php. and once you set a data in `session` you can use it from anywhere you want. 
To set data in session you don't need to do it globally you can do it in your login function.after that in your controller at current position put `public $current_email=$this->session->userdata('email');`

And access `current_email` as `$this->current_emai;` where you want.

to access variable in views you can do

```
$objCI =& get_instance(); //now CI object can be used
echo $objCI->current_email;
```

Comment: what do i do with the two lines below?

Comment: it says $this is not allowed. i also need to output the email in view. and it is not recognizing the value. how do i input session data?

Comment: it says that $this in the public declaration is not allowed

Comment: refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624058/declaring-a-variable-outside-a-function-in-codeigniter

Comment: for further understanding can you provide me with the whole code of the proposed solution

Answer (score 0):

Just Declare that variable as public

```
class Some_Controller extends CI_Controller {
```

// adding gloabal varibale that can be used by all function in this class.

```
    public $global_variable = "global_example";

    $this->load->library('session'); //Must be global       $this->session->set_userdata('email', 'email@hp.com'); //Must be global
    $data['current_user']=$this->session->userdata('email'); //Must be global


   public function index(){




    $data['people'] = $this->some_model->getPeople();
    $data['mapList'] = $this->some_model->getMapped();
    $data['appServList'] = $this->some_model->getApp_serv();


    $this->load->view('templates/header.php',$data);
    $this->load->view('some_page/index.php',$data);
    /*Serves as the homepage. Shows the list for services, mapped services to an application and the list for application,
    from here you can easily add edit and hide items*/

}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two points worth noting here:

First and the irrelevant one, you need to set such session data only after a successful authentication process, not with every single time at the top of a general controller.

Second and the important one, I understand what you say by **global variables**. When you start to design your app you feel the need of multiple **kinds** of controllers. For example, you may have `Admin_Controller`, `Backoffice_Controller` or `Ajax_Controller` controllers. Some may extend others. So when you say **global variables** I think you need such mechanism. So you set a variable in parent controller and it will be available in all derived controllers of your application. I recommend you to create a `Base_Controller` as your parent controller for all of the application controllers which contain the general logic/data for all other.

But the point is that CodeIgniter does not support controller inheritance by default. Take a look at [CI Base Controllers](https://github.com/sepehr/ci-base-controllers) project and read through the docs. It will help you achieve what you need, plus a better and DRY-oriented application design.